# SQL Server - 2008 Rank Function Efficiency

Tags: sql-server

I have the two below Rank Functions that give me the same results but could someone provide information on which way is more efficient or is this just a case of personal preference?

One uses the table PK and the other the latest UpdateDate for that Id.

```
select Distinct 
DENSE_RANK () OVER 
(PARTITION BY a2.id ORDER BY a2.updateddate DESC) seq_LatestUpdate_Date, 
DENSE_RANK () OVER 
(PARTITION BY a2.id ORDER BY a2.cdm_id DESC) seq_LatestUpdate_ID
```

Comment: Did you check what the estimated costs are for the two queries, using SHOW ESTIMATED EXECUTION PLAN?

Comment: I guess you are missing `)` after first `DESC`. Otherwise your query is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

First, any performance implications of the `dense_rank()` are probably entirely undone by the `distinct`.  If you ask another question with the full query, then it can probably be made more efficient.

Second, the only thing of interest from a performance perspective is whether an index exists on `authid`.  The best indexes would be `(authid, dcm_id desc)` for the second, and a similar index for the first.

Okay, there might be a wee bit of difference because the ordering columns are a little bit longer in the first case than the second (assuming simple types for everything).  But really, considering such performance differences is undoubtedly premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you posted there won't be any performance difference between the two.

As a general rule, if one of the causes a sort in the execution plan and the other does not then the one that requires a sort will be slower.

As written both will require a sort. To prevent a sort for the first one you would want this index:

```
CREATE INDEX nc_xxx1 ON a2(id, updateddate DESC) INCLUDE (<other rows returned by your query>)
```

For the 2nd you would want this index:

```
CREATE INDEX nc_xxx2 ON a2(id, cdm_id DESC) INCLUDE (<other rows returned by your query>)
```

It's also possible to create an index that covers both, including your clustered index.